# how to parse a Microsoft Word 97-2004 .doc file with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, doc

How can i parse with PHP a .doc file "Microsoft Word 97-2004 document"?

I can parse "normal" .doc files with

```
private function read_doc() {
    $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     //print_r($outtext);die();
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
}
```

but that doesn't work with Microsoft Word 97-2004 .doc files.
I just want to extract the pure text. Nothing else.

--> **Solution** is [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) like [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) recommends in his comment.

Comment: Take a look at a library like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) that can read BIFF-format .doc files

Comment: Mark, with PHPWord it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: At the end i had to install catdoc -> i wrote an own answer in this post

Comment: In case anyone is looking for it: the [.doc binary file format](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Word97-2007BinaryFileFormat(doc)Specification.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

At the end i had to install linux catdoc 0.94.2 to resolve the problem. PHPWord couldn't convert all the files in a correct way to pure .txt format.

So here's a solution for linux (for example Ubuntu or Debian-like) users:
On command line install catdoc

```
sudo apt-get install catdoc
```

If you are on a Windows Server, have a look at this. It worked also for me:

http://blog.brush.co.nz/2009/09/catdoc-windows/

Then in your PHP Code you can call it like this (for Linux calls):

```
$escapeFile = escapeshellarg($data['tmp_name']);
$command = "catdoc $escapeFile";
$output = array();
exec($command,$output);
$text = implode("\n",$output);
```

then you can do for example

```
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
echo nl2br($text) ;
```

to see the result on screen.

That's what for me works best up to now.
If someone has a better solution, please tell me.